# How to tune system settings for mongoDB on Linux?

Tags: linux, mongodb, virtual-memory

Trying to squeeze a lot out of one question here -- please bear with me.

Although the MongoDB man pages make several useful recommendations about system settings like ulimit (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/), and other production factors (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-notes/) they seem mysteriously silent on things like *virtual memory and swap settings.*

The closest we get to a hint is that "...the operating system’s virtual memory subsystem manages MongoDB’s memory..." (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#does-mongodb-require-a-lot-of-ram).

Running the same job - high writes and high reads on about 10,000,000 records in a single collection -- on my 4-processor, 4GB RAM macbook and an 8-core ubuntu box with 64GB RAM I saw dramatically WORSE read performance on the linux box with factory settings, and could hear the disk constantly spinning, indicating high I/O and presumably swapping. Yes, other things were happening on the box, but there was plenty of free RAM, disk space, etc.; furthermore, I did *not* see evidence that Mongo was expanding to take advantage of all that free RAM as it is touted to do.

Linux box default settings were as follows:
vm.swappiness =60
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 10
vm.dirty_ratio = 20
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs =3000
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs=500

I hazarded some guesses looking at docs and blogs for other types of databases (Oracle, MYSQL, etc.), experimented, and adjusted as below.
vm.swappiness=10
vm.dirty_background_ratio=5
vm.dirty_ratio=5
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs=250
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs=500

I saw some immediate apparent improvements in read time.  However, when I ran my test jobs again, read performance continued to be painfully sluggish during heavy writes.

Then, I REBUILT the collection from an available data source - and suddenly I can read at 1ms or less per record WHILE doing the write job!

So the question is really two-fold:

1) **What are appropriate VM settings for MongoDB on Linux?**
2) (bonus)  **Does Mongo do some checking or optimization with the OS while data is being built?**  In other words, if I have built a large data set with suboptimal VM or I/O settings, does Mongo make assumptions during the memory-mapping process that will fail to take advantage of optimizations down the road?

Obviously I don't fully grok memory mapping under the hood (I was hoping I wouldn't have to).

Any help appreciated...thanks!  -j

Comment: What storage configuration do you have on your macbook and on the linux box?

Comment: no longer have this setup - but i was more looking for guidelines on how to approach this kind of problem.

Comment: The reason they don't go into detail on specific server settings is because their business model is based on support costs, so they want you to pay for that information.

Answer (score 1):

I Think your case with 4 Gigs of RAM is pretty good covered here for Neo4j which also uses Memory Mapped IO and thus the same tuning measures should apply:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/linux-performance-guide.html

So from reading this I think your

```
vm.dirty_ratio=5
vm.dirty_background_ratio=5
```

are rather too low than to high.